# Where do I submit events on failure of my custom operator?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I'm working on a mysql users operator and I'm somewhat stuck on what's the proper way to report any issues.

The plan is to watch on CRD for `MysqlUser` and create `Secret`s and mysql users in the specified DB. Obviously, either of that can go wrong, at which point I need to report an error.

Some k8s object track events in the `status.conditions`. There's also the `Event` object, but I've only seen that used by kubelet / controllermanager insofar.

If say, I have a problem creating mysql user because my operator cannot talk to mysql, but otherwise the CRD is valid, should it go to event or to CRD's status?

Comment: Curious about your plans: Can you add more details on how you are planning to watch the CRD? Is it a secret which you reflect into the db?

Comment: CRD defines the username and operator writes a random password into a Secret and provisions the DB, yes. For now I have 1:1 mapping between username and DB name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRDs do not have a status part yet (1.7). Notifying via events is perfectly fine, that's the reason for having them in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to events reported from volume plugin (kubelet) where, for example, kubelet is unable to mount a volume from NFS server because server address is invalid, thus can not take to it.

Tracking events in `status.conditions` is less useful in this scenario since users typically have no control over how kubelet (or operator in your case) interacts with underline resources. In general, `status.conditions` only signals the status of the object, not why it is in this condition.

This is just my understanding of how to make the choice. I don't know if there is any rules around it.